# Finding a loose match for a string in arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm, substring

I have a huge array list which contains 1000 entries out of which one of the entry is "world". And, I have a word "big world". I want to get the word "big world" matched with "world" in the arraylist.

What is the most cost effective way of doing it? I cannot use .contains method of array list, and If I traverse all the 1000 entries and match them by pattern its going to be very costly in terms of performance. I am using Java for this.

Could you please let me know what is the best way for this?

Cheers,
J

Comment: Define "loose" match. Does one string have to be subtring of other? Would 'heart' and 'ear' match? Would these be english words/phrases? If we asked you to get rid of the ArrayList, would you be able to?

Comment: Yes your right! The word "heart" matches the "ear". I am flexible to use any kind of datastructure!

Comment: Some more clarification: Is the set of 1000 strings static? How exactly do you want to do the substring match? Given a word U, you want to find a word V in the arraylist such that V is a substring of U? If U is a substring of some other V', is that also a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split up every single element of the `ArrayList` into words and stop as soon as you find one of them.

I suppose by your profile you develop in Java, with Lucene you would easily do something like that

```
public class NodesAnalyzer extends Analyzer {   
    public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {

        Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(reader)
        TokenFilter lowerCaseFilter = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenizer)
        TokenFilter stopFilter = new StopFilter(lowerCaseFilter, Data.stopWords.collect{ it.text } as String[])
        SnowballFilter snowballFilter = new SnowballFilter(stopFilter, new org.tartarus.snowball.ext.ItalianStemmer())

        return snowballFilter
    }   
}

    Analyzer analyzer = new NodesAnalyzer()

    TokenStream ts = analyzer.tokenStream(null, new StringReader(str)); 
    Token token = ts.next()

    while (token != null) {
       String cur = token.term()
       token = ts.next();
    }
```

Note: this is Groovy code that I copied from a personal project so you will have to translate things like `Data.stopWords.collect{ it.text } as String[]` to use with plain Java

Comment: Lucene would be a good fit for this, especially if it grows beyond 1000 words.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you dont know the content of the arraylist elements. you will have to traverse the whole arraylist.

Traversing the arraylist would cost you O(n).

Sorting the arraylist wouldnt help you because you are talking about a searching a string in a set of strings. and still sorting would be more expensive. O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to search the list repeatedly, it may make sense to use the `sort()` and `binarySearch()` methods of [`Collections`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

Addendum: As noted by @user177883, the cost of an *O(n log n)* sort must be weighed against the benefit of subsequent *O(log n)* searches.

> The word "heart" matches the [word] "ear".

As an exact match is insufficient, this approach would be inadequate.

Comment: sorting would be more expensive than searching.

Comment: I could do that, but if you see the binarySearch is written to return an exact match. Though I may write a customized Comparator, it may be tough to identify a loose match.

Comment: how do you know if the user want to stop when user finds the value. what is the user wants to find all occurences of the string. then you will have to employ many binary search. each time you find an occurence, you remove it from the adt and you do another binary search, and the worst case you might end up doing n binary searches. your worst case complexity would be 2nlogn. which is very in efficient compared to sequential search.

Comment: An inexpensive binary search would make checking each word in the candidate string for an exact match feasible. As @Moron notes, it may be useful to clarify your match criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue.

Solved it by using this `if`/`else if` statement.

```
if (myArrayList.contains(wordThatIsEntered) 
    && wordThatCantBeMatched.equals(wordThatIsEntered)) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "WORD CAN'T BE THE SAME OR THAT WORD ISN'T HERE", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 

else if (myArrayList.contains(wordThatIsEntered)) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "FOUND THE EXACT WORD YOU ARE LOOKING FOR!", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```